# Is it possible to change the value of a register when a certain instruction is executed?

Tags: windows, x86, exception

I was wondering if it was possible to change the value of a register when an instruction gets executed. For example

```
0x10 call eax
```

Say `eax` contains `0x20` at that point, I want to add `0x10` to it so that the address that gets called is now `0x30`.

What I tried doing was set a `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` and put an `INT3` on `0x10`. When my exception handler gets called, I restore the original byte at `0x10`. Then I add `0x10` to `eax` and jump to `ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eip`. This obviously doesn't work well because I never return to the OS.

Is there another way or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so apparently you can just edit `ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eax` inside your

`LONG CALLBACK VectoredHandler(
  _In_ PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo
);`

function and the OS will set the eax to that value when it returns the execution back to where the exception was(If you return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION.)